# Ubuntu in failed state after upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 - How to recover?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I was running Ubuntu 10.04 and attempted to upgrade to 10.10.  I have a really slow connection (DSL 128kbits/sec) and copying the upgrade files took about 26 hours.  I of course let it run unattended.  When I came back, I notice the following 3 dlgs:

1.

```
Could not install the upgrades
The upgrade has aborted.  Your system could be in an
unusable state.  A recovery will run now (dpkg -- configure -a).
```

2.

```
gpk-update-icon
Distribution upgrades available
maverick 10.10 (stable)
[more information] [Do no show this again] [Cancel] [Ok]
```

3.

```
gpk-update-icon
Security updates available
The following important updates are available for your
computer:
libwebkit-1.0-2-dbg - Web content engine library for Gtk+ -
Debugging symbols
libcupsimage2 - Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Raster
image library
...
```

What is the best response to all of this?

I went through something similar in an attempted network upgrade from 8.04 to 10.04 and had to reload the unbootable machine fresh from distribution media (all data was lost).  I'd like to avoid that here.

I have not yet responded to the dialogs, and want to make sure the system is still bootable and not lose my data this time.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into a recovery console (root) from grub and try the following in order.

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```